# A cartoon (around 2009-2010?) about a huge muscular hero on a quest led by a small prince?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I don't remember much: the hero was bounded to help that small guy, a king's son I think, but he didn't really wanted to. So they were on a quest for a sword maybe? And it was a whole team of good guys. Around 2010 perhaps? Broadcasted by Fox Kids, Disney maybe?

Answer (score 6):

I think you might be talking about [World of Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Quest)

I don't remember a lot about it but the main character Quest's description matches what you're looking for and it was from 2008-2009.

> **Quest**: A strong warrior with an odd past. Previously, he was assigned as a nurse for baby Nestor. Quest first appears in Episode 1 when Prince Nestor arrives because his parents have been captured and he needs to find the Shatter Soul Sword so he can rescue them. Quest refuses until Nestor tricks him into activating an allegiance spell that binds him to the prince. His famous catchphrase is mostly. "I hate..." 'e.g. theme song, suckers, allegiance spell e.g'

[image: Title image for World of Quest]

**Opening Credits**